# read in values and store in list in c++

Tags: c++, list, stream, text-files

i have a text file with data like the following:

```
name
weight 
groupcode

name
weight
groupcode

name
weight
groupcode
```

now i want write the data of all persons into a output file till the maximum weight of 10000 kg is reached.

currently i have this:

```
 void loadData(){
            ifstream readFile( "inFile.txt" );
            if( !readFile.is_open() )
        {
            cout << "Cannot open file" << endl;
        }
            else
            {
                    cout << "Open file" << endl;
            }

            char row[30]; // max length of a value
            while(readFile.getline (row, 50))
            {
                    cout << row << endl;
                    // how can i store the data into a list and also calculating the total weight?
            }
            readFile.close();
    }
```

i work with visual studio 2010 professional!

because i am a c++ beginner there could be is a better way! i am open for any idea's and suggestions

thanks in advance!

Comment: This code has a horrible buffer overflow bug. Don’t use `char[]` together with `getline`. Use `std::string`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>

struct entry
{
    entry()
        : weight()
    { }

    std::string name;
    int weight; // kg
    std::string group_code;
};

// content of data.txt
// (without leading space)
//
// John
// 80
// Wrestler
// 
// Joe
// 75
// Cowboy


int main()
{
    std::ifstream stream("data.txt");
    if (stream)
    {
        std::vector<entry> entries;

        const int limit_total_weight = 10000;   // kg
        int total_weight = 0;                   // kg

        entry current;
        while (std::getline(stream, current.name) &&
               stream >> current.weight &&
               stream.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n') &&  // skip the rest of the line containing the weight
               std::getline(stream, current.group_code))
        {
            entries.push_back(current);

            total_weight += current.weight;
            if (total_weight > limit_total_weight)
            {
                break;
            }

            // ignore empty line
            stream.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "could not open the file" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Since you wannt to write the entries to a file, just stream out the entries instead of storing them in the vector. And of course you could overload the operator >> and operator << for the entry type.

Comment: hey simon, do you also know how i can display the data of the vector?

Comment: @burner007: Just iterate over the vector and print the relevant details out. But if you don't need the data after the while loop - just print it out while you are looping.

Answer (score 2):

Well here's a clue. Do you see the mismatch between your code and your problem description? In your problem description you have the data in groups of **four** lines, name, weight, groupcode, and a blank line. But in your code you only read **one** line each time round your loop, you should read **four** lines each time round your loop. So something like this

```
char name[30];
char weight[30];
char groupcode[30];
char blank[30];
while (readFile.getline (name, 30) && 
    readFile.getline (weight, 30) && 
    readFile.getline (groupcode, 30) && 
    readFile.getline (blank, 30)) 
{
    // now do something with name, weight and groupcode
}
```

Not perfect by a long way, but hopefully will get you started on the right track. Remember the *structure* of your code should match the structure of your problem description.

Comment: I suggest to use std::getline(..) with std::string - instead of using char arrays.

Comment: @Simon: Absolutely, and a class or struct to hold the different bits of data might be a good idea. But one thing at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Have two file pointers, try reading input file and keep writing to o/p file. Meanwhile have a counter and keep incrementing with weight. When weight >= 10k, break the loop. By then you will have required data in o/p file.

Use this link for list of I/O APIs:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364232(v=VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to struggle through things to build a working program on your own, read this.  If you'd rather learn by example and study a strong example of C++ input/output, I'd definitely suggest poring over Simon's code.

First things first:  You created a row buffer with 30 characters when you wrote, "char row[30];"
In the next line, you should change the readFile.getline(row, 50) call to readFile.getline(row, 30).  Otherwise, it will try to read in 50 characters, and if someone has a name longer than 30, the memory past the buffer will become corrupted.  So, that's a no-no. ;)

If you want to learn C++, I would strongly suggest that you use the standard library for I/O rather than the Microsoft-specific libraries that rplusg suggested.  You're on the right track with ifstream and getline.  If you want to learn pure C++, Simon has the right idea in his comment about switching out the character array for an std::string.

Anyway, john gave good advice about structuring your program around the problem description.  As he said, you will want to read four lines with every iteration of the loop.  When you read the weight line, you will want to find a way to get numerical output from it (if you're sticking with the character array, try http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/, or try http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atof/ for non-whole numbers).  Then you can add that to a running weight total.  Each iteration, output data to a file as required, and once your weight total >= 10000, that's when you know to break out of the loop.

However, you might not want to use getline inside of your while condition at all:  Since you have to use getline four times each loop iteration, you would either have to use something similar to Simon's code or store your results in four separate buffers if you did it that way (otherwise, you won't have time to read the weight and print out the line before the next line is read in!).

Instead, you can also structure the loop to be while(total <= 10000) or something similar.  In that case, you can use four sets of if(readFile.getline(row, 30)) inside of the loop, and you'll be able to read in the weight and print things out in between each set.  The loop will end automatically after the iteration that pushes the total weight over 10000...but you should also break out of it if you reach the end of the file, or you'll be stuck in a loop for all eternity. :p

Good luck!